# "Unlock to delete" on edit Subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have this table on linked to a database with a "Edit" on top-right.
I can delete swiping, but if I press the Edit button nothing happen!
I mean, I wrote a similar call for another table in the same program, and when i press edit, a small "Unlock to delete" appear; then if you press it you can delete the element/row...
not here!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Categorie";
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // A lot of code... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the tableView to begin editing with setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate

```
//Init your editBarButton
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editTable)];

//Init your doneBarButton
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneEditing)];
```

Here's the a sample action method:

```
- (void)editTable {
   if (!self.tableView.editing) [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
   self.navigationController.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneButton;
}

- (void)doneEditing {
   if (self.tableView.editing) [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
   self.navigationController.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButton;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Now it works. But ii doesn't show "Done" instead of "Edit" when i'm in editing mode.

Comment: You need to have another 'done' barButton that you switch with the edit button.  I'll update the code.

Comment: Perfect! Writing the code in your order I had "Done" button as I entered in the view, but I solved switching the two lines. Thanks a lot for your help.